# What happens if the ProgId of my com object is not unique?

Tags: c#, com, progid

Here's my class definition:

```
[ProgId("MyProject.MyClass")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("...")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  ...
}
```

What happens if a com client tries to create my object by the ProgId and there is randomly another one with the same ProgId?

Comment: Did you try it? What happens?

Comment: It is not going to be random.  The installer of the component that ran last is going to overwrite the older one.  Bad week for the user, typically.  Otherwise a basic reason why the [Guid] is the superior way, they are Globally Unique ids.  Don't use "MyProject", another programmer thought of that before.  A trade-marked product name or company name is wise.

Comment: thanks.. no worries.. I changed project and class name for this question :)